# Avoid activity chooser prompt for in-app deeplinks

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

In order to prepare for Instant Apps, I split my app into multiple modules with one activity each. Each activity launches another activity by throwing an intent with the destination URL (as opposed to class name).

The issue here is that the activity chooser shows up after each `startActivity` call. Users can select "always" for each activity, but doing it for 25 activities, navigating within the app will be a poor experience.

I can have `autoVerify=true` in the Manifest. This will help API level 23+. But any ideas how to support the older versions? InstantApp is supported until SDK 21, and my regular app is on API 19.

Comment: Show us the code that creates and sends an intend and the correspondig manifest entry. Usually you get the chooser when you have more than one activity matching or if you use createChooser.

Comment: if you don't need to respond to intents from other application.. may be you can use define custom actions and use intent-filters in your manifest.. that way only your app will respond and the system won't show activity chooser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the `DEFAULT` category to your intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       ...
</intent-filter>
```

See [this sample](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/blob/main/DynamicFeatures/instant/url/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L25) for more context.

Comment: The link provided in the sample now 404s

Comment: Thanks, @HBG. I just updated the URL to the new location.